# How to send ms teams personal tab's data to ms teams bot?

Tags: javascript, sdk, microsoft-teams, add-in

Other than using Graph API, is that possible to exchange data like strings or json objects from custom tabs browser to conversation's teams bot with any SDK feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can explain what you mean about 'exchanging' data, but yes it's possible to send a message from the tab into the conversation, either in a personal app (with a bot and a tab) or one inside a Team or group chat. Here is an example using 'Proactive Messaging' (there are links at the bottom of the page to more reading on the topic): [Proactive Messaging Sample](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging/)

Comment: I agree with Hilton solution, could you please try as suggested above and if it works for you please upvote the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about sending proactive message, I was think about a tab's localStorage data, is there a way way to send them to the bot and then use them as user settings for the conversation? It seems that the tab localStorage is not accessible in the bot so I'd like to find another way to send them to the team's bot without displaying them in the conversation in a message

Comment: localStorage is not recommended anyway because it would be locking the user to a single device (e.g. can't use the same app on their Phone)